# Laravel how to pass the value from controller to view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Actually I want to pass agency_id value to view from hyperlink so that whenever use clicks on the link on the basis of id controller will return the description of selected agency. How to do this?

View:
a href="http://localhost/exc/export_excel.php?id={{$agency_id}}">Export to Excel

Route:
Route::get ( '/agency-id', 'AgenciesController@agencyName' );

Controller: 
$customer->agency_id = Auth::user ()->agency_id;

How will i call the agency_id value in the view to link it with the URL? This value is single value and not an array.

Iam a Novice, still learning Laravel platform. Can someone pls help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess i didn't frame the question well.

Comment: If the `agency_id` is stored in the `User` model, which is the current logged user. You can call `auth()->user->agency_id` directly on blade.

Comment: In the blade can i try the below code? 'a href= "http://localhost/exc/export_excel.php?id={{ auth()->user->agency_id }}">Export to Excel</a>

Comment: Yes. Try first, dont ask every single time without even tried anything.

Comment: i got an error " Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user (View: D:\wamp\www\test\resources\views\customers.blade.php )

Comment: Sorry, the code should be `auth()->user()->agency_id`

Comment: use this {{ \Auth::user()->agency_id }} in your view. please check it is blade `filename.blade.php`

Comment: @Adlan. Yes its working. Thank you so much

Comment: @Bugfixer. Thank you